# Is this function with values greater than 1 a joint pdf?

Tags: probability, density-function

I want to construct a joint pdf for $X$ and $Y$ over the domain $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ as follows.
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}&(x,y)\in\Omega_1\\
\dfrac{3}{2}&(x,y)\in\Omega_2\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where the domain $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ is drawn as below:

[image]

If I try to integrate the pdf over $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, i.e.
$$\iint\limits_{\Omega_1} \dfrac{1}{2} dydx + \iint\limits_{\Omega_2} \dfrac{3}{2} dydx$$
the result is $1$.

However, I doubt this function is a joint pdf because the value of the function is $\dfrac{3}{2}>1$ for $\Omega_2$.

Is this function not a joint pdf?

Comment: the pdf is a density, not a probability function thus it can be >1. The probability for a bivariate joint pdf is a volume and your volume sums to 1. $f(x,y)\ge0$ everywhere thus yes, your function is a pdf

Comment: Are you saying that you want to define $f(x,y)$ to be a probability?  It is clear from the drawing that  $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ can form a probability distribution since together they could form a $1 \times 1$ square with area $1$.  (A single integral over the domain).  But is $f(x,y)$ a probability or is it a pdf?  For that matter, is the domain  $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ a probability distribution or is it a pdf that happens to occupy area $1$?